# sefer akeidas yitzchak

Tags: sources-mekorot, parashat-noach

where in sefer akeidas yitzchak (with the exact wording) does it mention that because the unity of those during dor haflaga (the generation of dispersion/ tower of bavel) had led them to this course of action and made its success possible, Hashem said that He would destroy their unity.

artscroll interlinear chumash [noach 11:7-8] writes "since their unity had led them to this course of action and made its success possible, Hashem said that He would destroy their unity (Akeidas Yitzchak)."

Comment: Would you consider others who state the idea an answer?

Comment: i might consider others if u have the exact source where i can easily find it, or the exact lashon...

Comment: sorry! i'm new to this... still learning...

Comment: No problem at all! Consider learning more with this short [tour](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/tour) and this short [Beginners' Guide](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/3887/8775).

Comment: B'reshit Rabba (38:6) 
ותן של דור המבול לא נשתיירה מהן פליטה ואלו של דור הפלגה נשתיירה מהם פליטה, אלא דור המבול על ידי שהיו שטופים בגזל שנא' (שם /איוב/ כד) גבולות ישיגו עדר גזלו וירעו, לפיכך לא נשתייר מהן פליטה אבל אלו על ידי שהיו אוהבים זה את זה שנאמר ויהי כל הארץ שפה אחת לפיכך נשתיירה מהן פליטה

Answer (score 1):

Chapter 14:

> ויהי כנסעם מקדם ט׳. אמנם היה ענינס כמו שאכאר, והוא כי למה שהיה אחד
>   מאופני החקירה על תכלית הנמצאות ותועלתם העמידה על הכרת תכונותיהם
>   ופעולותיהם המיוחדות. כמו שנשפוט שתכלית מציאות יסוד האש ותועלתו למזג בו
>   הקרירות והלחות מצד מה שנמצאו בו פעולות החום והיובש . וקי הענץ ביסוד
>   האויר ידוע למה שנמצאו בטבעי הלחות והחום וק מתמונת הכלי וצורתו יוכר
>   תכליתו ומעשהו. ועתה כמו כן ספר כי אנשי הדור ההוא למה שהרגישו בעצמם
>   המצאם על שפה אחת כלס גס ברצון מוסכם על דברים ועניניס אחדים. (א) גזרו
>   ברעתם שהתכלית המיוחד להם היא הקטן המדיני נשיותן הסדר בו לשתמשך ביניהם
>   השתיף והחברה על הצד היית־ נכין שאפשר ושזה המעולה שבתכליות האנושיות
>   ומצאו סמך לדעתם במה שנשאו עיניהם השמימה והכירו כל מערכות השמים
>   וכסיליהם כלם דיזים במעשיהם המתמידות אשר לא ימצא להם שוס תכלית אחר רק
>   שבסבובס ולכתם נותנין סדר נכון בהתמדת אלו הנמצאות ההוות והנפסדות ואמרו
>   מה יזכה ילוד אםה כי אם בשיפליא עצת דעתו ויגריל תושית שכלו להדמות
>   למעולה ממנו והקרוב אליו במעלה ולזה אמר ויהי מסעם מקדם וימצאו בקעה כארז
>   שנער ט׳. יאמר שהם לא חטאו במה שחשבו זה(א) אלא במה שישבו שם וראי זה
>   העסק תכלית לעצמו ולא שמוהו דרך אל תכלית גדול ממנו שהואטסק ההצלחה
>   הנפשייתכי האחד נתלה בעץ הדעת והמעולה ממנו בעץ החיים ובבנים אל שת ואל
>   הבל או אל שם ויפת כמו שאמרנו ולזה אמרו חכמינו ז״ל בנסעס מקדם מקדמונו
>   של עולם (ב״ר פ׳ ל״ח). ירצה כי בזה הסיחו דעתם מהסבה הראשונה יתב׳ שמו
>   ולא הגיעו עדיו במיונם איל גילו אצל הגרמים השמימיים ושם עמדו ולקחו מהם
>   ראיה כמו שאמרנו ולזה כשמצאו להס הבקעה ההיא ארץ טיבה ורחבה ונאותה מאד
>   לשבת בה בחרוה לישיב׳ משאר המקומות ייאמרו תיש אל רעהו הבה נלינה לבנים
>   ונשרפה כו׳. (ב) הודיע הכתוב הדברים האלה להורות וללמד שכיר נזדמן להם
>   בפעולותיהם החיצונות הענין עצמו אשר היה בפנימיות מחשכותם במעשים האלו
>   וזה שהוא מפורסם שהבקעה ההיא איצה ארץ הרי מחצב שיוכל לחציב מהם אבנים
>   שלמות אבנים יקרות אבני גזית אל בנין כמוהו וכבר אמרו חכמינו דל והיתית
>   אין חדא ושומת על פיס מבא (דניאל וי). וכי יש אבנים כבכל אלא שקמתה מארן
>   ישראל ובאת וישבה על פי הבאר(במדבר רבה פ׳ י״ד). אמנם היוצמצאים שם חלוקי
>   נחל ואבנים סלעיים אשר לא יאיתו לזה המין אס מפני קטנם ואס מפני שאינן
>   מקבלות הכתית׳ והגזיזה. ולזה הוכרח להם לעשות מהעפר לבנים ולשורסש שיהיו
>   להם תחת האבנים ולשרוף מהאבנים הסלעייסההם לעשות מהם סיד והנה בעקר הבנין
>   נזדמן להם דבר פחות ממה שהיו צריכין כמו שהוא ידוע שהאבנים היו יותר
>   טובים להם מהלבנים אמנם בחמר אשר בו יבנו הינץ נזדמן להם יות־ ממה שהיו
>   צריכיןכמושהחמרהוא הסיד הוא יותר חזק ועז מהחמר הנעשה מהאבנים הגדולים כי
>   על כן בחרו הביצים החמר לבנין האבנים והחומר הוא לבנין הלבנים החזק לחזק
>   והרפה לרפה אכל הס נזדמן להם החמר החזק תחת החמר הרפה כמו שבפנימיות
>   מחשכותס נתחלף לתם התכלית העליון הנפשיי אשר הוא ?עקר. לתנליח פחות ממנו
>   והוא ההצלחה המדינית וגם נשתמשי בתכלית הפחות ההוא כדבר היותר יקר שנמצא
>   בהם שהוא השכל העיוני כי גזרו שאין לו עסק אחר זולת זה. סיף דבר שיעורו
>   ופירושו ותהי להם כקשת המפורסמות מקום המושפלות והשכל העיוני היה להם
>   מקום השכל המעשי והוא מה שנאמר ויאמרו הבה נכנה לנו עיר ומנדל כו׳.כי ראו
>   שעקר שלמותם הוא כהיותם גוני עיר גדולה וכה יתקיים הקבוץ המדיני והשלמתו
>   כמו שראה קין זה הענץ עצמו ויהי בונה עיר (כראשית ד) כי חשכו שהמעש׳ ההוא
>   יצרפס ויקריכם לשמים כמעלה כי כמו הם יעיינו תמיר בסדור אלו הנמצאים
>   והשלמת פעולותיהם בכל מה שקצרה בו יד סדור הגרם השמימיי להשלימו עד שנמצא
>   ראשו של זה בעקרו של זה. ולחשבם זה התכלית העליון שבתכליות אמרו ונטש׳
>   לנו שם . כי התכלית העליון מיוחס אליו כמו שהוא בשער י״ב ואמרו פן נפוץ
>   על מי כל הארץ כי לא ראו לבקש שאר התכליות שנזכרו שם שהס תחתיו וכיש
>   שמאסו להם שער נ ח ארבעה עשר להם ללכה למט על לעצים כמו כנהכאר כי הוא
>   ההפסד למוחלט: וירד ה׳ לראות את לגייר ואה המגדל כו׳, יאמר שירד לסוף
>   דעהם ובנגלה לפניו מקום המעדה רגליהם וניר: איהס באומרו ויאמר ה׳ הן עם
>   אחד ושפה אחה לכלס כו׳. כי מהמבואר אצל לחוקרים בהסבה יטצמיה שהספיק לחדש
>   דבר וללמציאו מכ״ש שהספיק להעמיד אוהו ולקיימו ודומ׳ לזה אמרו חכמינו ז״ל
>   מהי דלא הוה לוה מאי דלוה לה כל בכן (סנהדרין ע׳׳א .) . (נ) ולזל אייר לן
>   עם אחד ושפה אהה וזה יענין הוא עקר ההחלהכ הכר ממנה הולידו זה המשפע אשר
>   החלו לעשות ועהה כעוד נסכה הזאה קיימה ודמי לא יבצר מהם בכל הכר יזייי
>   נעשיה כי •והר נקל הוא להחמיר והמשך הדבר שככר נמצא מלחדכו והמציאו . ממי
>   תקנתיהו הבטל הסכה ויסתלק כמסוככ . (ד) ולזה אמר הכה נרדה ונכלה שם שפתם
>   ט ׳. ועס זה יגזרו כדעהס ממקום שכאו שאין התכלית המיוחד לאדס הקמץ המדיני
>   ורם כיוכ כוח שכבר נתפרדה לשונם. אכל תכלית אמר נכבד ומעולה ממנו אשר
>   התאחדו כו אע״פ שיפיצו על פני כל הארץ והוא כדבור כשכלי לפנימי אשר לוא
>   ה׳ ושוה בכל יעמיס וללשונות . ונזה ויפץ הי• אוהכ ט׳ כדי כיהנו אל לנס זה
>   ה הכליה המעולה המשותף לכל ולזה ויחדלו לבניה חת העיר כי הרגישו כענין
>   וחדלו להם ונפצו כארצות. והוא מה שאמר כי כהכללה׳ שפת כל האדן ומשם הפיצם
>   ה׳ לומר כי כככלכל להם לכונס נסהלקה ההחלהס ומשם למדו שהכוונה האלהית ה
>   יחם שיהיו נפוצים על פני כל הארז רק כיהההדו כדבר כלא יפרידולו •הבדלי
>   גויס וגבולות כמיס. (ה) והנך רומה כלא היו חייבים הלו לאנשים עונש חמר
>   זולה זה והוא לקעקע היסוד אשר עליו היו בונים בנינם כסבורים שהיה יסוד
>   חזק ונאמן ועם זה כבר כבב הדבר אשר אליו היהה מחנכתו הראשונה ולוה ה׳
>   מלכרשים חכר עליהם הוכהה בריה הקשח והיא הנפוץ כאכר חממו. ונרי ראיה כי
>   כמעט נטיו רגליהם בהסכמתם והתאר׳דוהם היא היה מקום ה ממדחס לולי ה׳ כי
>   טוב וישר הוא ויורה חטאים ופושעים בדרך עיינה כמו שהוא נ מוייב מדרך
>   לבלמוה . יעל דרך שאמרו חכמינו ז״ל בא ליטלר מסייעין אוהו (כבה ק״ד.) וזה
>   כעניןגס כן הוא דורך מהלך הבלמוה להוייה להדם וכלמוה צורתו כי על כן נאמר
>   וירד ה׳ לראות כוי אשר בנו בגי כאדם לומר כעדין לא גגמרה צורתו עד הנפוץ
>   הזה אשר יוציאנו משמשו הראשון:

In Chapter 14 the Akeidat Yitzchak Writes:
(Translated and Condensed by Eliyahu Munk)

> 1) The story of the tower of Babel is the corollary of this newly
>   established covenant. On the one hand, the episode of Noach getting
>   drunk illustrated that the attitudes of his three sons had indeed not
>   remained identical. On the other hand, the Torah seems to stress **their
>   unity of purpose which resulted in the enterprise of building the
>   tower of Babel.**
>
> Mankind believed that their goal must be a unified one, and that all
>   of them should reside close together. Observing the order prevailing
>   in the heavenly constellations, and the fact that they all seemed
>   arranged around a central figure, i.e. the sun, they decided to build
>   their civilization by emulating that system. They did this once they
>   had moved into the valley out of their mountain caves, having learned
>   to use rainproof bricks for building.
>
> G'd in His wisdom, did not intend for mankind to remain closely
>   bunched together. **Man erred in believing that their concentration was
>   an end in itself, rather than a means to an end.** When urbanization is
>   the means to achieve moral perfection of man, then it is laudatory.
>
> 2) Granted that stones and rocks are more enduring building materials
>   than fired bricks, the fact that they were prepared to abandon the
>   former in favour of the latter, showed that their primary objective
>   was the policy of clustering together, as stated in Genesis 11:5 "lest
>   we be scattered on the face of the earth."
>
> Having thus traded a higher moral purpose for the lower political
>   purpose of togetherness, G'd decided to interfere before further
>   unwelcome negative manifestations had a chance to develop.
>
> Man's collective thinking had become dangerously close to the thinking
>   of Cain, who had excelled at being a "builder of cities" (Genesis
>   4:17), and who also believed that this would bring him closer to
>   Heaven.
>
> 4) G'd decided that some physical dispersal, while preserving the
>   spiritual ideal of striving towards moral perfection intact, was
>   preferable to mere physical togetherness. In this way, parallel to the
>   advent of the deluge, a further step was taken towards making man
>   concentrate on the attainment of higher objectives.
>
> 5) When G'd "descended," He examined their basic reasoning. **When He
>   found that their actions were rooted in their being united, i.e. like
>   a regiment, single minded and of identical modes of expression, He
>   decided to change the course of their actions and disperse them.** Thus
>   He caused linguistic changes due to change of habitat. Unity
>   henceforth ought to prevail in their striving to become servants of
>   the Lord etc., not in matters pertaining to boundaries etc. Thus their
>   error was of a kind that did not require further corrective action.
>   (punishment)
>
> One of the basic lessons we learn is that man must employ his
>   speculative faculties and not remain content with remaining static.

Comment: ...can anybody **bold** the answer in the hebrew that @RCW posted?

Comment: @user13898 Hebrew selection is riddled with mistakes to the point it doesn't appear to be the correct passage at all.